# nuxt2 tiptapを導入してビルド(yarn build)が出来ない: Cannot find name 'type'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, webpack, yarn

### 概要

nuxt.jsを使ってLP作成のエディタを作成しようと[tiptap](https://tiptap.dev/)というエディタのライブラリを入れたのですがビルド時(yarn build)にエラーになるので解消したい。

### 仕様技術、前提

- vue2
- nuxt2
- typescript

#### 導入ライブラリ

package.jsonの差分を記載（yarn addで追加）

```
    "@tiptap/extension-color": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/extension-focus": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/extension-image": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/extension-link": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-align": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-style": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/pm": "^2.0.0-beta.218",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
    "@tiptap/vue-2": "^2.0.0-beta.209",
```

### ビルド時のエラー

yarn build(npm run build)をすると以下のようなエラーが出る

```
ERROR in /workspace/nuxt/node_modules/@tiptap/starter-kit/dist/packages/starter-kit/src/index.d.ts
ERROR in /workspace/nuxt/node_modules/@tiptap/starter-kit/dist/packages/starter-kit/src/index.d.ts(2,8):
2:8 Cannot find name 'type'.
    1 | import { StarterKit } from './starter-kit';
  > 2 | export type { StarterKitOptions } from './starter-kit';
      |        ^
    3 | export * from './starter-kit';
    4 | export default StarterKit;
    5 |
```

省略するが、同様のCannot find name〜というエラーがたくさん出るので解決方法を教えてほしい。

Comment: TypeScript のバージョンはいくつですか？　`export type` は [TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) から入った機能なのでバージョンが古いと構文エラーになります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
3.75なのでそれが原因でした！ありがとうございます！